# Can't connect Windows Azure VM with MySQL On-premise

Tags: mysql, firewall, virtual-machines, azure

I have a VM on Windows Azure with Windows 2008 R2, and I'm trying to open a connection to an on-premise MySQL database hosted on another network. We cleared the VM's public IP (the one displayed on the VM's dashboard) from the other network's firewall, but the VM still can't open the connection.

Is there an additional firewall setting that I might need to configure from the VM? The on-premise MySQL database is supposed to have public access, but it is hosted in a corporate network.

I tested the VM with db4free.net and it was able to connect to it successfully.

Comment: I suspect you'll find the source IP the inbound MySQL request is originating from isn't the same as you've put onto your firewall. The better scenario to manage this would be to put in a VPN connection via an Azure Virtual Network (VNet) that would tunnel the data to your VM. This obviously requires the right VPN kit on-prem and your performance may not be that great depending on latency.

Comment: http://windward.net/blogs/moving-databases-to-azure-a-step-by-step-guide/ I went through the same process but in the opposite way (trying to connect to the Azure VM from an on-prem server) and I recorded all of the firewall and other permissions and obstacles I faced while doing so in the link above. Hopefully this will help you as well.